# two tables, each with a foreign key referencing the other

Tags: database, sqlite, foreign-keys

I am trying to create a database to store some questions and answers for a quiz

I have so far two tables:

`questions: (Question ID(PK), question string, correct answer ID)`

`answers: (Answer ID(PK), answer string, question ID)`

I'm having trouble setting up the foreign key constraints. Surely I need to make sure that `correct answer ID` exists in `answers` and that also `question ID` in `answers` exists in the `questions` table. However, when trying to add these foreign keys in SQliteStudio, I am getting errors which suggest I cannot add a foreign key referencing table A > B when there is already a foreign key constraint that goes from B > A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior is correct. Otherwise, you'd get a chicken-and-egg problem: you would not be able to insert an answer without inserting a row for the question first, and you also would not be able to insert a question without first inserting a valid answer for it. You will get a similar issue trying to delete a question or an answer being referenced.

A typical solution to this is adding a column `is_correct` to the `answer` table.

Comment: I did think about the chicken and egg scenario, but then I assumed you could just add the rows with `null` values in the foreign key fields and update them after all the rows were added. I suppose that opens you up to other potential problems though. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I also like the solution you presented as it allows the possibility of multiple correct answers to a question

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_schemacommands

> The ALTER TABLE command works differently in two respects when foreign
>   key constraints are enabled:
>
> It is not possible to use the "ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN" syntax to
>   add a column that includes a REFERENCES clause, unless the default
>   value of the new column is NULL. Attempting to do so returns an error.
>
> ...
>
> The intent of these enhancements to the ALTER TABLE and DROP TABLE
>   commands is to ensure that they cannot be used to create a database
>   that contains foreign key violations, at least while foreign key
>   constraints are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think this situation can be modeled with a relation table:

`QA: (Question ID (FK), Answer ID (FK), Correct, ...)` and the 2 FK's represent the PK of table.

Answer (score 0):

1. Specific to your problem:
   There is no problem on setting up foreign key constraint among two tables both referring one another when tables are empty in spite of whether foreign key column is nullable or not.

But when Both these tables are filled with data then we have to keep in mind primary key data and nullable type of foreign key column. for example
Table Question

QuestionID Question    AnwerID
         1 'Question1'       1
         2 'Question2'       2

AnswerID   Answer      QuestionID
       3   'Answer1'            3
       4   'Answer2'            4

Now if you try to set up foreign key constraint then u fails because these are already violating the foreign key rules.

Simple thing is You will be able to set up foreign key constraint only when your current data does not violate them.

1. If the foreign key columns does not allow null in case of your scenario then after setting up foreign key constraint, You are limited to only current data in third column (QuestionID or AnswerID)
2. Even if you are able to implement it using NULL then same applies to the deletion.
   You have to trac both table: setting null to corresponding column in referring table
   Drop table will not work

Better Approach:
These QuestionID, AnswerID should be mapped to another table SchemaName.[Mapping]
Use your logic for correct answer ID. consider N*N mapping whether you support or not.

Do not link both table internally.